# Which bpy.data.objects option controls the color of the object's texture?

Tags: python, texturing, scripting, color

[image]

I have 784 cubes in my scene right now, and I can loop through all 784 of them by using

```
for i in range(784):
    bpy.data.objects[i]
```

Each cube represents a pixel which is in grayscale color, a value between 0.0 to 1.0. I already have my colors extracted from a 2D grayscale image and now I just want to transfer the corresponding brightness value to the cubes. Basically, do:

```
bpy.data.objects[i].find_its_color_options.change_brightness_to(0.873)
```

and repeat for all 784 cubes. I am currently using blender 2.8 but I don't think this is going to be much different than 2.79.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use in `bpy.data.objects.active_material.material.diffuse_color` you can set the diffuse color, and there are some other properties that may be useful [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material) and [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object)

In my experience, materials are tricky with scripts. You need to remember that materials are separate from the objects, so if the same material is assigned to every cube, changing it for one material will change it for all of them.